# Loading jQuery asynchronously in IE causes error - but $.ajax() still runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, asynchronous

Scenario:

I have some JS code, I want to detect if jQuery exists in the DOM already, if not add it:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'function') {
    var sc = document.createElement('script');
    sc.type = 'text/javascript';
    sc.async = true;
    sc.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js";
    sc.onload = function() { App.getTrackers(); };
    sc.onreadystatechange = function() { App.getTrackers(); };

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, s);
}
else {
    App.getTrackers();
}

App = {
    getTrackers: function() {
        $.ajax({url: "/ajax.php", success: function(data) { console.log(data) }});
    }
}
```

The onload() is for FF+Webkit; onReadyStateChange() is for IE

The issue is with IE, I'm getting this error:

```
'$' is undefined
```

Yet! IE's console returns the contents of ajax.php. So the jQuery function has been executed... somehow. Even though $ was undefined...

Does $ not yet exist? Has it yet to be compiled even though the script has been downloaded?

Comment: Have you thought about compatibility mode?  Instead of $(....) you can do jQuery(...) instead.

Comment: Yes I will be removing all $ calls since it's not my website that will be running this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ready state has other values than `complete`, so the event will be triggered at different stages until the code is loaded and completed.

Check what the state is in the event handler:

```
sc.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (sc.readyState === 'complete') {
    App.getTrackers();
  }
};
```